# 404: file not found. Laravel failed to load home.blade.php file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to the Laravel framework, so I'm following this tutorial, cloning instagram. 
After designing the front end, all was going well, until I started working with `php artisan`.
I have created the user and profile database, migrated them successfully, and linked them in a one-to-one relationship.

But, after this, trying to login, and navigate to home, I'm getting a

> 404, not found error

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

**profileController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class profilesController extends Controller
{
     public function index($user)
    {
        $user = \App\User::find($user);
        return view('home', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**homeController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */       
}
```

**web.php:**

```
  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'profilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
```

profile created via php artisan

```
$profile->user
=> App\User {#2975
     id: "1",
     name: "Sofolahan Eniola Ademola",
     email: "princeademola85@gmail.com",
     username: "usertesst",
     email_verified_at: null,
     created_at: "2019-07-27 16:01:45",
     updated_at: "2019-07-27 16:01:45",
   }
>>> $profile
=> App\profile {#2965
     title: "cool stuff",
     description: "desc stuff",
     user_id: 1,
     updated_at: "2019-07-27 16:04:45",
     created_at: "2019-07-27 16:04:45",
     id: 1,
     user: App\User {#2975
       id: "1",
       name: "Sofolahan Eniola Ademola",
       email: "princeademola85@gmail.com",
       username: "usertesst",
       email_verified_at: null,
       created_at: "2019-07-27 16:01:45",
       updated_at: "2019-07-27 16:01:45",
     },
   }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by navigate to home? What URL do you go to?

Comment: I created a make:auth which gives me access to the login and register. Once the login is clicked, and credentials are supplied and checked, it ought to navigate to the homepage. But it's saying 404.

Comment: The auth will by default attempt to route you to the `/home` path after login, but you have no route in your `web.php` that has defined that route.

Comment: Is there something in the logs ./storage/logs/?
On which URL do you get 404, /home? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#included-authenticating

Comment: When I changed the route to Route::get('/','profilesController@index' );

And I removed the {{$user -> username }} it worked, but when I add {{$user -> username }} which is suppose to dynamically print the username. It gives:

property [user] does not exist on the collection instance

Comment: If you want the logged in user, you can pass `return view('home', [
            'user' => Auth::user(),
        ]);` - your issue now is that you don't pass a value to the route, it should be `Route::get('/{user}', 'profilesController@index');` and you can access the URL as `/1` to get the user of ID 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, after a successful login, it directs you to '/home' which is missing in your web route.

```
Route::get('/home', homeController@index')
```

You can replace homeController with the name of your controller and index with this method.